# interior points and limit points of $\{(x,y): x^2+2y^2 < 1\}$

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Find out all interior points and limit points of $ A =\{(x,y): x^2+2y^2 < 1\}$

I understand this problem graphically, but i'm not quite sure how to prove the answer rigorously using mathematical word.

My try : Let k be an element of A, and suppose t is an element of $\{(x,y):x^2+2y^2 =1\}$, which makes minimum $||t-k||$. Then $N(k,\delta)\subset A$ when $\delta = \||t-k||$.

I suppose this will work, but I want more clear and detailed proof.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you mean $(x,y)\in \mathbb{Q}\times \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde oops i forgot it. $(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2$

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to show that $A$ is open is probably noticing that $A$ is the preimage of the open interval $(1, ∞)$ with respect to the continuous mapping $(x, y) ↦ x^2 + 2y^2$. And similarly, using the preimage of $[1, ∞)$, every boundary point of $A$ lies in $\{(x, y): x^2 + 2y^2 = 1\}$. For the other inclusion $(x, y) ∈ \overline{\{(tx, ty): t ∈ [0, 1)\}} ⊆ \overline{A}$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as a starter, this is somewhat hard to understand for me. Would you please explain more?

Comment: @user432019: In the first part, I claim that every point of $A$ is an interior point of $A$, i.e. $A$ is an open set. And I prove it by using the fact that a mapping is continuous if and only if every preimage of an open set is open… Does it make sence for you? Or which part or notion you don't understand?

Comment: Thanks for additional explanation. Now i started to understand what you mean. I'll try it for myself.