# Another solution to the problem of finding the interior points and limit points of $A=\{(x,y):x^2+2y^2<1\}$

Tags: general-topology, analysis

[interior points and limit points of $\{(x,y): x^2+2y^2 < 1\}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2218984/432019)

Find out all interior points and limit points of $A=\{(x,y):x^2+2y^2<1\}$ ($(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2$)

I've got an answer from original post but as i'm not familiar with this subject, I cannot understand the solution.
Is there any other solution?

Comment: You should ask this in your original question. Repeating the same question is not the best way.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Sorry, I'm not familiar with this site. Again sorry for my mistake.